# zlib incorrect header check decompressing git pack

Tags: c++, git, compression, zlib

I'm trying to parse a git pack which I received with a POST to
`https://github.com/codecrafters-io/git-sample-3/git-upload-pack`
and the data being
`0032want 23f0bc3b5c7c3108e41c448f01a3db31e7064bbb\n00000009done`
and stored the returned string in `std::string pack`. To parse the string, I did the following

```
    pack = pack.substr(20, pack.length() - 40); // skip 8 byte http header, 12 byte pack header, 20 byte pack trailer
    int type;
    int pos = 0;
    std::string lengthstr;
    int length = 0;
    type = (pack[pos] & 112) >> 4; // 112 is 11100000 so this gets the first 3 bits
    length = length | (pack[pos] & 0x0F); // take the last 4 bits
    if (pack[pos] & 0x80) { // if the type bit starts with 0 then the last 4 bits are simply the length
        pos++;
        while (pack[pos] & 0x80) { // while leftmost bit is 1
            length = length << 7;
            length = length | (pack[pos] & 0x7F); // flip first bit to 0 si it's ignored, then we append the other 7 bits to the integer
            pos++;
        }
        length = length << 7;
        length = length | pack[pos]; // set the leftmost bit to 1 so it's ignored, and do the same thing
    }
    pos++;
    FILE* customStdout = fdopen(1, "w");

    FILE* source = fmemopen((void*)pack.substr(pos, length).c_str(), length, "r");
    std::cout << inf(source, customStdout) << "\n";
```

Where inf comes from [zpipe.c](https://www.zlib.net/zpipe.c). The inf call results in `Z_DATA_ERROR` with msg `incorrect header check`

I actually printed out the bits in binary and the bits starting at pos are what I expected for the zlib header (`78 9C`), so I'm not sure why I'm getting incorrect header here.

I also tried using `inflateInit2(&strm, -MAX_WBITS)` and adding 2 to pos to skip the header altogether, but it returns the same error with message `invalid stored block lengths`

Comment: You didn't say what platform you're on, but you may need to use `"rb"` with `fmemopen()`.

Comment: On mac but this did not appear to make a difference for me

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the `inf` call with the following code

```
    int ret;
    unsigned have;
    z_stream strm;
    unsigned char in[16384];
    unsigned char out[16384];

    /* allocate inflate state */
    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
    strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
    strm.avail_in = 0;
    strm.next_in = Z_NULL;
    ret = inflateInit(&strm);
    strm.avail_in = pack.length() - pos;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16384; i++) {
        in[i] = pack[pos + i];
    }
    strm.next_in = in;
    strm.avail_out = 16384;
    strm.next_out = out;
    inflate(&strm, Z_NO_FLUSH);
```

allows the inflate call to succeed. The only difference I observe is that I copied the characters from pack directly into the stream buffer. I suspect the issue had to do with the way I was creating the files